# Cannot GET an Express Route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with ExpressJS route and everything works not until I added a route in which I get the error message,

`Cannot GET /api/users/abc`

using Postman.

Below are images that describe the challenge right now.

From my `server.js` file

[image]

To my `userRoutes.js` file

[image]

Every route works fine but `/user_stats` route doesn't. My approach to debugging the problem is to create an `/abc` route but to no avail, I got this HTTP response from Postman

[image]

Now the question, what might have gone wrong in my code?

Comment: Seems your code is all ok. You can stop your node server and run again. It should work.

Comment: I did that severally before and did that again. Still the same error.

Comment: Can you put `/user_stats` and `/abc` route in the top section on your `userRoutes.js` and try again?

Answer (score 0):

It seems after adding the route you haven't started the server. So, to make sure every time you made any changes to the files get reflected in the server build, you should install `nodemon` and make it run.

```
npm install --save-dev nodemon // only for dev
```

To run :

```
nodemon [your node app]
```

For more details check [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon), how you can configure your server to run the build files.

Comment: Thank you for the attempt. I use `nodemon` to start the server. Still the same error. Every route works fine till now except when I added the `/user_stats` route and `/abc` route. Those two routes are not running while others are.

Comment: Register '/' route at the end and try if that works.

Comment: I just did this now, still the same error.

Comment: Is it possile for you to setup this piece of code some where on server? i can check it there. Your code seems fine, there must be a spelling or some minor mistake.